# Sql Server - Foreign key referencing multiple columns one of which isn't in the source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

I've got a problem with foreign key. This is my DB structure (simplified):

Table 'Languages'

```
LanguageID - primary key
LanguageName - string (for example 'English')
..
```

---

Table 'Users'

```
UserID - primary key
LanguageID - byte (FK to Languages.LanguageID)
..
```

---

Table 'Localization'

```
LocalizationID - / compound primary key
LanguageID     - \ compound primary key (FK to Languages.LanguageID)
Data - string (for example 'My Program' in English)
```

---

Table 'UserLocalization'

```
UserLocalizationID - primary key
UserID - which user (FK to Users.UserID)
..
some other useful columns -> this table cannot be removed **EDITED**
..
LocalizationID - what string (FK to Localization.?) <- oops, not really because 
                                                       LanguageID is needed 
                                                       for FK to 'Localization'
```

How to make a FK (or any other integrity check) in 'UserLocalization' to 'Localization'. Is it possible in this configuration ? Or is it not ok, and therefore some restructuralization (really ?) is needed ? If so how to accomplish it ?

**Edit: A bit cleaned up for better clarity.**

Comment: Clean up the references -- you have tables A/B/C, but you have notes about FKs to named tables (string, language, etc).

Comment: Hi, 'string' and 'language' tables are not tables from this scenario, those are FKs outside this scope. I've added a note to them. To ignore them.

Comment: My wild guess is that you want another field (Type) in Table C and a composite foreign key `(ID_B, Type)` that references the (composite) primary key of Table B.

Comment: It would be better though to show us the names of the tables so we understand better the structure and if further normalization is needed.

Comment: Well, is there a way how to not store the duplicate information. I don't really want to store language in this table, it's just redundant data. Is there another way ? This link-table will be vast, and I'm trying to keep it low. Also to synchronize between TableA.Type and TableC.Type (suggested) will be complicated.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to edit it futher.

Comment: Aha, I guess I stumbled upon solution while making suitable example. What I need is a table 'Strings' which is missing in my scenario.

Comment: In your example, should all `Users` with the same `LanguageID` have the same `Localization.Data/String` values?  e.g. if you have two users who are both German, would they both have/need the same `Localization` records, or could they be different?

Comment: They should be the same.

Comment: In that case, your point about needing a `Strings` table (or `Labels` if that's a better name) is sensible.  That would allow you to define a complete list of string/labels that would be referenced by a FK from your `Localization` table.  Then see my answer about using some SQL instead of the `UserLocalization` table.

Comment: The 'Strings' table would be a solution, but it seems to me pointless to have two tables for one entity. Which is localization, if they weren't fixed. My question maybe really should be. Is there a way to fake computed (virtual in fact) column (automatic synchronization) to pose as a second key for 'Localization' table. Damn, it is key table in my application, and I don't want to get it wrong. The table 'UserLocalization' should be really small (as it will grow big) and fast. I don't wanna join two tables (when touching/selecting from 'UserLocalization') it can be really expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: if you have your table `Localization` like this:

```
LocalizationID - / compound primary key
LanguageID     - \ compound primary key (FK to Languages.LanguageID)
Data - string (for example 'My Program' in English)
```

and you want to add a foreign key to another table referencing this table, that foreign key needs to have **both columns** of your PK here at hand, so it could be:

Table 'UserLocalization'

```
UserLocalizationID - primary key
UserID - which user (FK to Users.UserID)
(LocalizationID, LanguageID) - FK to Localization
```

That's one of the downsides of compound primary keys - any FK referencing them must also include **all** columns of the compound PK - no exceptions / tricks / workarounds possible. With two columns, that's still doable, but with four, five, ten columns it gets really really messy. It also means any `JOIN` to that table must contain **all** common fields - and again, with two it's still ok, but with more, it gets really messy.

This is one of the reasons I would often consider adding an artificial surrogate key to tables where I only have a compound PK - just to simplify FK joins to it.

Comment: Hi, I chose this way because I want to alleviate the load to the 'UserLocalization' table. For performance reason I wanted to remove the need to join 'Localization' table. The reason is that table 'Languages' contains only 3 rows (fixed). So only 3 possible LanguageIDs, and 30 possible LocalizationIDs (also fixed). The whole 'Localization' table is therefore fixed. Moreover the table 'UserLocalization' will contain billions of records. If I put a standalone unique key (one column) to 'Localization' it would require a - otherwise perfectly ok - join whenever selecting from 'UserLocalization'.

Comment: If it was possible to make persisted computed column something like: ComputedLanguageID as (select u.LanguageID from Users u where u.UserID = UserID). Because the key is available there, just one hop away. :D

Comment: If the other tables in your database are small then I wouldn't worry about the performance of doing joins at this stage.  If it turns out to be slow at a later date then you could look at using an Indexed View.

Comment: I guess you're right. I was considering the materialized view, but it will be ok. I just freaked out, because it is a potential bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `UserLocalization` table.  Use this SQL instead to find the localized strings for the users:

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Localization ON Users.LanguageID = Localization.LanguageID
```

All users with the same language need/have the same localization records, so you don't need to add any more integrity checks; you're doing all the checks already with the FKs on `LanguageID` in the `Users` and `Localization` tables.

If you want to find a specific user's localized data/strings just put a `WHERE UserID = [Whatever]` on the end of the SQL.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the UserLocalizaton contains more of its data. Status for example. I guess I should have made it clear in the question, but it didn't occurred to me that someone would optimize the table away completely. But surely this would be the solution for the scenario I've posted originally. I'll edit the question to lower the confusion.